# php regular expression

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this tag in a php string:
`<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Log in" class="form-submit ajax-trigger" />`
that I'd like to replace with
`<a href="#" onclick="document.user-login.submit();" class="sign-in">sign in</a>`

I'm pretty sure that I need to use the php function `preg_replace` but I'm not sure of the regular expression. Is it possible to make a regular expression that will replace all `<input type="submit" />` tags regardless of what additional properties the tag has?

Comment: Rather depends what you want to replace it with, what the attributes contain and how well formed your XHTML is.

Comment: Take care the `user-login` is an invalid tag id; you need an underscore there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That aim is simplistic enough for a regex to work. In your case:

```
 $text = preg_replace('#<input\b[^>]*\s(type="submit")[^>]*>#i',
                      '<a href="#" onclick=".....', $text);
```

(Check out some of the [regex design tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) for future needs.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern to catch all input tags as you described. It will strip out the additional properties of the tag, which I think is what you're asking for.

```
/<input type="submit"[^/]+\/>/
```

I didn't test this myself, but it should get you going in the right direction. The [^/]+ is the key; it catches all characters that are NOT "/" up to the trailing "/>".